# Retrieve images according to ID in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I wanted to retrieve machine image pass by id. But issue is that i would be getting all machine images instead of particular one. So please guide me what's wrong i have done.

```
    <?php
                
            $query1=mysqli_query($con,"select * from photo where m_id = $m_id");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    ?>
         <img src="<?php echo $row['location']; ?>" height="150px;" width="150px;">
    <?php
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should filter data using WHERE to fetch only certain rows.

Answer (score -1):

Just Add:

```
$m_id = $_POST['m_id'];
$query1=mysqli_query($con,"select * from photo where m_id = $m_id ");
```

hope this help